# BigDecimal undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm getting an error when i'm trying to average out a column from search results:

```
undefined method `each' for #<BigDecimal:101780440,'0.1776030511 706048E4',27(45)>
```

View

```
<% @vone.each do |v| %>
<%= "%.2f" % (v.lint/227) %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
@vone = Result.where(params[:variety_one], params[:years]).includes(:trial).where(params[:region_id], params[:irrigated]).average('lint')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method 'average' returns number, hence it doesn't respond to 'each' method

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average

If you want to iterate through the result, then you should remove the average

```
@vone = Result.where(params[:variety_one], params[:years]).includes(:trial).where(params[:region_id], params[:irrigated])
```

Comment: Thanks andypp. Could I call the average in the view?